# What does ClassName::class mean in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

When I read code written in the Laravel framework, I see a lot of uses of `ClassName::class`. What does is the meaning of the modifier `::class`? Is this a feature of Laravel or PHP? I've searched but been unable to find documentation.

Comment: [This](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) link takes you to the correct page in the PHP docs that explains class name resolution.

Answer (score 43):

> Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name of the *ClassName* class by using `ClassName::class`. This is particularly useful with namespaced classes.

For example

```
namespace MyProject;
class Alpha{ }

namespace MyOtherProject;
class Beta{ }

echo Alpha::class; // displays: MyProject\Alpha
echo Beta::class; // displays: MyOtherProject\Beta
```

Answer (score 12):

It just returns the class name with namespace! 
Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name of the ClassName class by using ClassName::class. This is particularly useful with namespaced classes.

```
namespace NS {
    class ClassName {
    }
    echo ClassName::class;
}
```

The above example will output:

```
NS\ClassName
```

Comment: Ok, but then what do you with that string that is output???? How do you call a method within it?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer [to this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)

```
::class
Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name resolution.
```